# Admin mode breaks with subdomains in latest WP

Tags: admin, subdomains

This is the symptom/issue - I am using a subdomain, and latest Wordpress Rev, as well as PHP on server. When signed in to my site as admin, if I choose admin/customize, I get a new signon screen within a frame and message "Session expired. Please log in again. You will not move away from this page."

I've confirmed this error occurs regardless of theme. 
And WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) match.

Last, for what it's worth, I've had this subdomain running for well over a year with no issues, it only shows this symptom recently. As if the Rev of WP were the issue.

UPDATE - I backed up my data, and reinstalled from scratch. The problem is no longer appearing.

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone will be able to guess without access to your server. Obviously you have some cookie problem but it is impossible to guess from the symptoms what is the cause.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. When something runs for a long time and suddenly 'breaks' I was hopeful that I wasn't the only one. If using subdomains is common, maybe others are seeing the same issue. If not, I have little understanding how to start troubleshooting.

Comment: it always possible that something changed on your PC. can you recreate it on another computer? I don't think there was any cookie related change it 4.3.

Comment: Just checked - same issue on other PC.

Comment: Like Mark mentioned, its bit difficult to mention the exact cause unless we have atleast your website URL. The issue could be with setting up cookie which may happen if you have different siteurl and homeurl. To give it a try, please edit your wp-config.php file and add these two: 
**define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://abc.example.com/'); define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://abc.example.com/');**
Please replace **abc.example.com** with your actual subdomain. The thing to make sure is both URLs should match.

Comment: If above does not resolve, then one more thing you can try is setting your cookie domain to the subdomain **define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'abc.example.com/');** If this does not help then please share your website URL.

Comment: @ItsMePN - If you change this to an answer (both of your comments add up to good advice) I will accept and you get the 50 points.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Just added this as an answer. I am curious to know which one solved your problem though? Is it my first comment or the second?

Comment: I updated my question - I decided to just rip it out and reinstall from scratch. The site was just one page with 50+ RSS feeds, so no posts or anything. It was faster to do it from scratch than to continue trying to get help trouble shooting. If I run into this again, I'll re-visit your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be with setting up cookie which may happen if you have different siteurl and homeurl. To give it a try, please edit your wp-config.php file and add these two:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'abc.example.com/'); 
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'abc.example.com/');
```

Please replace abc.example.com with your actual subdomain. The thing to make sure is both URLs should match.

If above does not resolve, then one more thing you can try is setting your cookie domain to the subdomain

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'abc.example.com/');
```